# codeigniter: Get baseurl in constant file

Tags: codeigniter

In one of my project I wanted to keep HTTP path in the constant file, but when i am declaring say define("STATIC_PATH", base_url().'static/profile_images');

It's throwing error. how it can be fixed, i know alternative method but wanted to keep it in same file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a constant with functions in PHP, only scalar and null values are allowed.

Scalar values are: integer, float, string and boolean.

So you should define your constant writing down the URL by hand.